# How does ThreadLocal<T>::getMap work?

Tags: java, thread-local

Considering that threadLocals is a private variable in Thread.class, I do not understand how [ThreadLocal::getMap](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/lang/ThreadLocal.java#212) is able to do  `t.threadLocals`.

Answer (score 1):

It isn't private, it's package-private (no visibility modifer) and both `Thread` and `ThreadLocal` are in the `java.lang` package.

Answer (score 1):

It is not private, but package-private. And `java.lang.ThreadLocal` and `java.lang.Thread` are in the same package.